# In R can we password protect workspace?

Tags: r, security, workspace

I am completely new to R. Need your help on this.

I have created two workspaces say A and B.

Is there any way i can restrict users of workspace A from accessing workspace B and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

The workspace is the interactive environment you are working with, while working in R. In that sense, two users do not have direct access to each others workspace.
If you refer to the saved workspace, when quitting R, then no. At least not from R.

However, say your two users are working on the same desktop. If they have different user profiles, which they log in with, then you can limit access to each others saved workspaces, simply by limiting the other user's access to your folder.